# Fermi Dirac Distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, fermions

Understanding Fermi Dirac Distribution using the graph[image] As the temperature rises why the slope of the graph changes.
Explanation with an analogy is appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? It's a distribution and that is the end of it.

Comment: Read [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics) and then provide a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At zero K all electrons fill up the available states from the bottom up to the Fermi energy. You therefore see a sharp cutoff at the Fermi level what in the plot looks to be 5eV. Once they start gaining energy in the form of a temperature change, they can diffuse into upper states, but with smaller probability (hence only a small tail that breaches higher eV at the low probability end).